# Change attributes in CSS class with JQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I can't figure out how I can change an attribute in a CSS Class. Right now I add a style to that specific div, but what I want is for the attribute in the CSS class to be changed, and not just overridden by the new style attribute.

An example:

```
.example{background-color:blue}

<div class="example">example</div>
```

So how can I then change the background-color in the .example CSS and not just by overriding it like this:

```
<div class="example" style="background-color:blue">example</div>
```

I have tried a lot of things, but I cant figure it out. I have tried `.attr()` and `.css()`, but am I missing something.

Comment: Should work with just `.css("background-color", "blue");` yes?

Comment: can you show the jquery code that you are using?

Answer (score 4):

You can't change the actual CSS of the class (well you can, but it's extremely difficult and against practice) -- but you can change it for everything that is applied to that class now:

```
$('.example').css('background-color', 'blue');
```

What you can do however, is re-apply that CSS whenever a new element of your type is generated. For example, after calling an AJAX script that retrieves data from another file:

```
$('#blah').load('script.php', function() {
    $('.example').css('background-color', 'blue');
});
```

You can also have an interval that re-applies on all elements for you, but performance wise this is **not** recommended:

```
setInterval(function() {
    $('.example').css('background-color', 'blue');
}, 100);
```

My advice to you would be to find another way to mark your changes, like a second class and use that class to inflict the changes on your elements.

Answer (score 0):

What you want isn't possible, but something like this might be better.

```css
body.blueTheme .example { background-color: blue; }
body.redTheme .example { background-color: red; }
```

Now instead of changing the color in your event handler, change the class of the body.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamically changing style sheets is normally a bad idea, unless you're intending to implement complete re-theming.

It would be generally better to find some other way to mark the elements so that they acquire a different style, but if you *must* do this, you can dynamically change which stylesheets are loaded.

Put an `id` on a `<style>` element that links to an external CSS file:

```
<link id="dynCss" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="..." />
```

and then put the two different variations of the style in two different CSS files.

and then you can use:

```
document.getElementById('dynCss').href = ...
```

or

```
$('#dynCss).attr('href', ...);
```

which will then load (and apply) the new styles in the new URL.